# Is "hail from (somewhere)" necessarily formal English?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english, formality, colloquialisms

Macmillan dictionary says *hail from* is "formal".

[link](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/hail-from)

Cambridge dictionary notes *hail from* as "formal"  in British English  but doesn't say this for American English.

[link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hail-from-somewhere?q=hail+from)

Oxford Learners dictionary (American English) says *hail from* is formal. 
[link](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hail-from?q=hail+from)

Oxford dictionary doesn't stipulate. 
 [link](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/hail#nav2)

The OED does not mark the phrasal verb as formal–or archaic (*contra* the well-received [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/317307/is-hail-from-somewhere-necessarily-formal-english#comment721050_317307) to this post).

**So is *hail from* actually or even necessarily  formal, in some or any dialects of English?** And again: How are we to characterize this word for, say, non-native speakers of English?

I  had the idea it was colloquial/informal (in American English), as in something Mark Twain would say. My understanding is not necessarily correct.

Comment: I would call it archaic or humorous, not formal or informal; but also I am a Canadian, not a Brit or an American.

Comment: http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=46497126 - http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=46497229

Comment: It is almost certainly derived from the nautical use of the word, implying that its formality has likely changed over the past 200 years or so.  But I doubt that it was ever rigidly formal -- it lacks the stiffness necessary for that, plus nautical words would tend to be regarded as "crude".  [Bartlett {"Dictionary of Americanisms," 1848} identifies *to hail from* as "a phrase probably originating with seamen or boatmen."](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hail)

Comment: I have no idea how to read those charts @snailboat, what importance to put to them, or  what you would have me think about the verb in question by posting the links.

Comment: Note that you have to define "formal English".  If you're being presented to the Queen it's unlikely that you'd be announced as "hailing from Mayberry, North Carolina".

Comment: @HotLicks It is multiple dictionaries saying the verb is formal. I can't define what they mean by that, except to me formal English would be the kind spoken in formal contexts. Whether that extends to addressing royalty is beyond my ken.

Comment: Go figure, I actually perceive it as *informal* rather than formal.  (SAE speaker)  I can't say though if that view would be shared by others 'round where I'm from, though.

Comment: @guifa This is my thought, exactly, with regard to American English  It sounds *folksy*. Could it be that the same phrase could be considered both decidedly formal and decidedly informal?

Comment: I dunno why @Josh61 would remove his answer, as it did contain helpful data from AmE sources. Plus Peter Shor's Ngram link was helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I have time right now to write up an explanation, but it's pretty easy to figure out.  Anyway, I'm not trying to make you think anything in particular. I'm just providing a link to a thousand examples of real usage in present-day AmE so you can judge for yourself whether it tends to be used in formal English, informal English, or both.  The subcorpus of unscripted spoken English is about 20% the size of COCA as a whole, by the way.

Comment: It's possible. I can envision times when I might use it in a paper and it may give off of a formal air, but I use it colloquially as well. Because if the wealth of dialects and registers, it's very possible for a word to be informal, formal, *and* unremarkable with respect to formality at the same time. A word like *reckon* (unremarkable in SAE, but perceived by GAm speakers as informal, unless spoken by a Brit in which case they may perceive it as formal — I don't know if the word itself is considered formal in BrE but my guess is it's unremarkable)

Comment: If "I hail from X" is formal, then I don't know what formal is.  There is nothing wrong with the expression, it is probably standard somewhere,  -- but formal?  (Native English speaker from BosWash corridor.)

Comment: @ab2 So, for clarity's sake, you would **not** classify *hail from* as formal, correct?

Comment: @AlanCarmack Correct, I would classify it as colloquial.  But some heavy hitters classified it as formal, and I wonder why.  Colloquial https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=colloquial

Comment: I personally, being from Australia, would regard it as rather normal, though somewhat colloquial maybe in certain uses. It certainly would not be too remarkable to say 'I hail from Britain', if not a bit dated, but I would find 'I hail from New Zealand' to be a bit odd and rather put on.

Comment: I've tried to imagine it in my head in both formal and informal contexts.  "Well, howdy d'ere, friend!  Where d' y'all hail from?" and then "Good day, sir.  From whence dost thou hail?"  It doesn't sound weird either way.

Comment: No I remember who you are. You didn't complain about my links and copy and paste for your answer!!!

Answer (score 4):

**Specifics:**  I can find no evidence whatever that ‘hails from’ is ‘*necessarily* formal’ in any particular form of words, in any instance of English anywhere.  That does not mean that it does not figure in some process somewhere (maybe English-speakers getting mortgages in Bangalore *have* to use this term in declaring where they are from), but it does not indicate a conventional change to a formal register.

‘Hails from’ is commonly applied to people and their backgrounds, but it can legitimately refer to the relevant or influential origin of anything.

In my experience, ‘hails from’ signals that someone’s identity and/or character is in some sense derived from *that place*.  It is much stronger than ‘comes from’, which *could* mean no more than ‘is currently camping in’.

To me (long-term student of many Englishes, and UK inhabitant) the expression ‘hails from’ in that sense feels comfortably *traditional*, rather than archaic.  With that in mind I wondered whether I might find it in Tolkien, so I went hunting online.

This delivered no direct quotes from the *Lord of the Rings* books (I bet it’s there!), but unexpectedly it revealed a calmly consistent *and current* usage across many websites indicating the general sense of influential or notable personal history that I had in mind.

Examples...

- [wikia.com discussing the Corsairs](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Men):  *Pirates who hail from the
  havens of Umbar are masters of the sea and ships.*
- [Laura Hayes on the LotR characters](http://www.infoplease.com/spot/lotr-characters.html):  *Legolas is a valiant elf
  chosen to represent his people in the Fellowship. He hails from
  Mirkwood and is a great archer.*
- Gino Acevedo (Weta Workshop, and *LotR* film extra) [introducing
  himself on his website](http://www.arwen-undomiel.com/HCrew_Bios/Gino.html):  *Has spent most of his working life in
  Los Angeles although he hails from Arizona*

The emerging central point seems to be that *coming from* somewhere can be a simple matter of convenience or historical accident.  *Hailing from* somewhere contributes (however unspecifically) to *defining* you... otherwise you wouldn’t phrase it like that.  We don’t know *why* Mirkwood is relevant to Legolas being ‘valiant’ and ‘a great archer’, but we have the impression that it has been somehow conducive to those qualities.  We don’t know exactly *why* Acevedo doesn’t simply say he lives in LA and has done for ages, but for some reason he is *also* careful to let us know that he *hails from* Arizona.

**Discussion:**

In the absence of *positive* evidence of formality...

The designation ‘formal’ is probably misleading here, implying that ‘hails from’ introduces some kind of *ceremonial* significance to conversation in British English.  It has no such general cultural weight, that I am aware of.  In this kind of case, ‘formal’ seems to mean that everyone understands it but would normally say something more vaguely casual.

Of course there may well be established forms of words where it is used as a matter of form and habit (perhaps the Best Man conventionally ‘hails from’ somewhere in certain wedding formats), but ‘hails from’ does not automatically signal any specifically formal approach or tone (with a proviso for exaggeration or irony, below).

On the other hand, ‘hails from’ *does* have a generally weightier significance than ‘comes from’.

Someone introducing me could reasonably say any of the following, as a general way of helping people to get an initial handle on me:

- ‘He comes from London’ (because that was where I was born)
- ‘He comes from Bristol’ (because that was where I went to school and
  grew up)
- ‘He comes from St Andrews’ (because that was where I first studied,
  got married, and lived for a while)
- ‘He comes from Milton Keynes’ (because that is where I currently
  live)

The third of those is a bit of a stretch, but it has happened, and any of them could be adopted to give a given group an appropriately helpful perspective.

***Hails from***, however, conveys a much stronger and more singular sense of *belonging* and *connection*.  If you tell people that I hail from somewhere, you are telling them that I emphatically bring with me something of *that place* rather than any other, as part of my character.

If you say of someone, ‘He *comes from* Yorkshire,’ you basically just convey that that gives us something to talk about (birth, study, whatever).  It *might* be gigantically significant (‘He comes from Mars’ works fine), but it need not be at all.

If you say, ‘He *hails from* Yorkshire,’ you are saying (whether or not you intend to) that that is an active part of this man’s identity.  That heritage is going to form a noticeable part of how he interacts with us.

The proviso...  Humorous use of ‘hails from’ is possible, making it seem more generally formal than it is, comparable to someone shouting ‘Greetings!’ when you enter a pub.  (That, too is ‘formal’ in the sense that it is transparently understood but not commonly used.  It sounds a bit like something for special occasions.)  In such an atmosphere, saying that someone *hails from* Wootton Bassett is tantamount to saying that this by-the-way formality is frankly unimportant, and now that we have it out of the way we should forget it and get on with drinking.

Also... ‘Hails from’ need not refer to individual human background, although that is the sense in which we usually encounter it. For example, Thomas Hardy's poem [‘The Fiddler’](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5fHrAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT287&dq=%22Poetical%20Works%22%20%22thomas%20hardy%22%20%22the%20fiddler%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRv5ujpvfLAhUBsBQKHUrJAzgQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Poetical%20Works%22%20%22thomas%20hardy%22%20%22the%20fiddler%22&f=false) includes the line ‘Music hails from the devil’ (in describing the fiddler's function of driving a devout wedding ceremony to debauchery).

Comment: Very thorough. In America, I often hear this term from sportscasters, especially college. Also from game show hosts--I would hardly say formal. But still it seems a little type-cast, perhaps only because of specific examples within American culture.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. As a native speaker of American English, I would reject your point that *hails from’ does have a generally weightier significance than ‘comes from’.* I think you are reading something into *hails from* (as opposed to *comes from*). If I say *I come from Texas and this is the way I'm used to doing things*, this has the same meaning you intend for *hails from*.

Comment: Also I can't but think of the song lyric *I come from Alabama with a banjo on my knee* (from 'O, Susannah'), which also includes (in some versions) *I said I come from dixieland, Susannah don't you cry!*  Seems a perfect time to use *hail from* both due to  the 'weightier significance' you feel it has, but that I don't.  Also the use  of *come from* also points, in this, case to *hail from* perhaps sounding too formal for the setting (but not because of the import you give to the expression).

Comment: @AlanCarmack I completely agree with you. I am claiming, proposing or just noticing that 'hails from' comes with something of that built-in. As you say, you might declare,: 'I come from Texas and this is the way I'm used to doing things.'  You could get exactly the same effect by staring at someone across the sawbench and saying, 'Well, _I_ hail from Texas.'  And, anyway, 'I come from Texas' _could_ legitimately mean that that is where your tent currently is, or you are currently studying there. I wouldn't expect to hear 'hail from' used like that.

Comment: Anyway, the Question was about whether or not it is formal, and I think that out in the wild it is not.  It is also not archaic:  you don't have to be educated to understand it.  In my experience, however, it seems to represent a more definitive _declaration_ about what to expect from someone than 'comes from'.

Comment: Oh, and incidentally...  I am very fond of 'Oh Susanna', and it starts off with, 'I _came_ from Alabama with a banjo on my knee'.  Later it says (a few times), '_I've come_ from Alabama with a banjo on my knee'.  The narrator is reporting _the act of travelling_ from the south to New Orleans. He is not talking about heritage.  I might say, 'I've hitch-hiked from Bristol with a rucksack full of bricks', to similar effect.

Comment: @AlanCarmack - Stephen Foster was a child of the American heartland of Pennsylvania, Ohio, and points south.  He would not have come into much contact with people from the Eastern Seaboard where "hail" would be more apt to be idiomatic, and even if he were familiar with the word, he would have avoided using it, as it was not idiomatic for the Southern dialects which he chose to mimic.

Comment: @CaptainCranium - I come from Kentucky, near Louisville, where Stephen Foster was something of a minor deity.  I've heard *Oh Susanna* easily a hundred times, and I have *never* heard it sung with "*I came* from Alabama".  That may be the way it's written somewhere, but it's not how it's sung.  It's "Oh, I come from Alabama ...".  (Heck, next someone will claim that he's going to Louisiana rather than Looziana.)

Comment: @HotLicks I'm sure you're right.  Everyone everywhere has done 'Oh, Susanna', and I don't want to make claims for_absolute correctness_.  (I do lecture on adaptation and related legitimacies, after all.) In this case we might be faced with someone mimicking (as you say) tenses in a rather superficial way. Without your geographical advantage, I have simply reported my general experience of this song. It has been both sanged and wroted as I've given. As it happens, there's a nice, minor account of sorts on YouTube (www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZXvxOXXdCk).

Answer (score 1):

According to the 1847 Constitution of Liberia (as quoted in [1850 US senate documents](https://books.google.com/books?id=9sYDAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA3-PA48&lpg=RA3-PA48&dq=%22It%20is%20further%20enacted,%20That%20all%20vessels%20hailing%20from%20ports,%20and%20sailing%20under%20the%20flag%20of%20this%20Republic%22&source=bl&ots=oadK_mVvJu&sig=sHUApcTK4sAO9k9ggvLLLfsd9Es&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjovZm2nYfMAhVJ0h4KHR_iAEMQ6AEIIDAC#v=onepage&q=%22It%20is%20further%20enacted%2C%20That%20all%20vessels%20hailing%20from%20ports%2C%20and%20sailing%20under%20the%20flag%20of%20this%20Republic%22&f=false)):

> Article 1. Sec. 2 It is further enacted, That all vessels hailing from ports, and sailing under the flag of this Republic, are hereby prohibited from any and every species of intercourse with slavers, at sea and elsewhere...

So it is formal enough to be used in a country's constitution.

Comment: In 1850, when referring to sailing vessels.  In the same document which uses "intercourse" to mean "interaction".  I think standards may have changed.

Comment: @HotLicks sure, but the OP says "I had the idea it was colloquial/informal (in American English), as in something Mark Twain would say".  So it was not slang in the Mark Twain era, it was suitable to use in formal writing.

Comment: Saying a boat "hails from" some port is nautical jargon.  Saying that some person "hails from" some (possibly land-locked) country in Eastern Europe is metaphor.

Comment: @HotLicks "To call; to call to a person at a distance, to arrest his attention. It is properly used in any case where the person accosted is distant, but is appropriately used by seamen. Hoa or hoi, the ship ahoay, is the usual manner of hailing; to which the answer is holloa, or hollo. Then follow the usual questions, whence came ye? where are you bound? etc." http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/hail

Comment: Yes, but is it ***necessarily** formal*? That is, must it be used only in formal contexts? Is it  always considered "formal" in register?

Comment: No, it isn't necessarily formal.